# How to fix my donut icing patch?

Tags: rendering

I didn’t notice this patch since I have been working and I know it wasn’t there before. I was going through my render and I saw this odd patch on my donut which I have almost completed. I have just finished working on my lighting. How can I fix this without distributing my progress?

[image]

[image]

Comment: to share your file, read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Could you please highlight the problem? What patch are you talking about?

Comment: @moonboots I'm sorry, I am not quite sure what you mean by highlight, but I'll try to be a bit descriptive. If you change it from solid viewpoint to render viewpoint, on the top of the icing, you can see that my icing has a triangle shaped patch. it shows the donut color rather than the icing color. In solid mode, top of the icing, you can also see the cut out triangle shape showing the absent of the icing. I hope this makes sense, and thank you for being patient with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just that the icing is penetrating the donut, switch to *Edit* mode, enable the *Proportional Editing* option and the *Move* tool, select a vertex and move it:

[image]