# Some Part of Donut are missing, how can i fix it?

Tags: rendering

I have encountered an issue with missing parts in a 3D model of a donut that I'm working on. I'm using Blender, and I'd like to seek your guidance on how to address this problem.

Specifically, parts of the donut seem to be missing in the rendered output, and I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. I've already checked for issues in the model's geometry, normals, and rendering settings.

Could you please provide me with some advice or steps to troubleshoot and rectify this issue in Blender? I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: See if https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293670/how-to-fix-my-donut-icing-patch?rq=1 fixes the problem.